# Package to install bash script that needs root/sudo access

Tags: 18.04, bash, security, zenity

Is there a way to create a Snap/Snapcraft or Debian package that could install a bash script as an "application" with an icon in the Dock--specifically, one that needs to be run as root in order to perform drive operations?

This is the script source https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jeffbillings/PrintDCP/master/printdcp

Answer (score 1):

Jeff!

Linux ignores setuid bits on shell scripts, and thereof it is the case with Debian and Ubuntu distributions. This is due to an inherent race condition involved in executing setuid root shell scripts that is described in detail in answer on this link:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts

Hope this helps.

gmt42